# How to close a JFrame from a class outside the one it was declared in

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, awt

So I'm programming the game snake in Java, and in one class I declare my JFrame. As you can see, I use some class variables from my other class `GamePanel` (`HEIGHT` and `WIDTH`) to set dimensions as well as make an instance of `GamePanel` for `setContentPane()`. I have another class that makes an instance of SnakeGame in order to actually run the game. This class will have a title screen.
Here's the SnakeGame class:

```
    public final class SnakeGame{
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("SnakeGame");
     GamePanel g = new GamePanel();
     public SnakeGame(){
          //the content of the frame is the g object from the GamePanel class
          frame.setContentPane(g);
          //default close operation is to close when close button is pressed
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          //user can't change size of panel
          frame.setResizable(false);
          frame.pack();

          //size is set
          frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(GamePanel.WIDTH, GamePanel.HEIGHT));
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          //set visible = true so that the user can see it
          frame.setVisible(true);
     }
}
```

I want the user to be able to press the 'esc' key or press an on-screen button to close `frame` from the `GamePanel` class. Is there any possible way to do this?

I tried using a method in the `SnakeGame` class that would return `frame`, thinking I could call that method from my `GamePanel` class to use JFrame methods to alter `frame`, but that didn't seem to work.

Here's the constructor for `GamePanel`, if it helps whatsoever:

```
public GamePanel(){
          setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
          setFocusable(true);
          requestFocus();
          addKeyListener(this);
     }
```

Comment: Possibly call a method from the class containing the `javax.swing.JFrame` which closes the JFrame. Either way, I'm pretty sure that other class WILL need to access that JFrame.

Comment: Personal preference would be to use an observer, which would notify interested parties that some action should take place.  Swing calls them listeners, but they are the same concept

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor` function from `javax.swing.SwingUtilities` to get the top frame of the panel.

Here is the working code:

```java
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    if (arg0.getKeyCode() == 27) { // 27 is ascii code for esc button
        JFrame frame = (JFrame)SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
    }
}
```

Put this code in the `GamePanel`'s  `KeyPressed` function.